# import font awesome in web component

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome, web-component

This is my header component :

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <ul>
      <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-regular fa-bell"></i></li>
      <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></li>
      <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

This code can display the icons in fontawesome when I import the font-awesome before the closing body tag in my index.html file.

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/my id.js"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However, now I learnt web components. I created a header.js file for my header.

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
<div class="icon-container">
      <ul>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-regular fa-bell"></i></li>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></li>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i></li>
      </ul>
</div>`;
class header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Create a shadow root
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

window.customElements.define("header-section", header);
```

Now, the other part of html is still rendering, but the icon disappear, so how should I solve this?

Comment: Note that the font **is** available in shadow roots; it's just the CSS classes that are unknown there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the font-awesome icon fonts are not being loaded in your web component, the icons are not being displayed. To solve this, you can load the font-awesome in your web component using the link tag in your template.

Here's how you can modify your template:

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-jkihXtPklFJy8q3rnoEMBstczhBwFwO48lEQ7EDKlA5JX7xu5Q0NVg7lLeK/cHhV7hly0iygDRNyo6N88U6B9g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="icon-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-regular fa-bell"></i></li>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i></li>
        <li class="list-item"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i></li>
    </ul>
</div>`;
```

Answer (score 2):

for use in shadowDOM you need to load the CSS both in shadowDOM **and** globalDOM.

Make your component check if the link exists in globalDOM,
if not; the Web Component adds the href

```js
customElements.define('my-fa-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    let href = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.0/css/all.min.css";
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
           .innerHTML = `<style>@import url('${href}')</style>` +
           [`check`,`square-check`,`circle-check`,`gear`]
             .map(icon=>`fa-${icon}: <i class="fa fa-${icon}"></i><br>`).join("");
    if (!document.querySelector(`link[href="${href}"]`)) {
      document.head.append(
        Object.assign(document.createElement("link"), {
          rel: "stylesheet",
          href
        }))
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<my-fa-element></my-fa-element>
```

Comment: Rather than assigning the CSS via `innerHTML` to a `style` tag, I'd try to import the stylesheet, and push that into the shadow root's `adoptedStyleSheets`. That way you only ever load the CSS once, and a single Stylesheet object will be used for all instances. The only unfortunate thing about that is the fuss about import assertions with regard to CSP, and the consequential downgrading from Stage 3 to Stage 2.

Comment: Yes, should now also work since Apple adopted this (finally) 3 weeks ago: https://caniuse.com/?search=adoptedStyleSheets So be aware of Browser support

Comment: To avoid the FOUC (flash of un-styled content), you will want to pre-load your font in your index.html header. The method in the OP is good but will flash content the default "unknown character" until the font is loaded.